# Kafka messages not delivered to consumer

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

I am facing a very weird problem over here. I started a Kafka consumer using sarama-cluster library in go to consume some messages from a kafka topic. But the messages are not being received by the consumer being started.

However, a very weird thing is happening. If I start another consumer parallel to it, the messages are suddenly being delivered to both the consumers.

I cannot think of a logical explanation to it. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Note : This problem started after the Kafka and Zookeeper servers were started non-gracefully.

Here is the go code of consumer for consuming the messages which is not working:

```
if err := consumer.Start(); err != nil {
    return err
}
updChan, err := consumer.Consume()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case msg, ok := <-updChan:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            var message liveupdater.KafkaMessage
            err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Msg, &message)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            err = handleMessaege(message)
            if err != nil {
                logrus.Println("encountered error:" + err.Error())
            }

            consumer.MarkProcessed(msg, string(message.Type))
        }
    }
}()
```

Following is the go code where consumer is receiving messages(the only difference between this and previous code is another consumer running in parallel for same topic).

```
consumeMessages(config)

if err := consumer.Start(); err != nil {
    return err
}
updChan, err := consumer.Consume()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case msg, ok := <-updChan:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            var message liveupdater.KafkaMessage
            err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Msg, &message)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            err = handleMessaege(message)
            if err != nil {
                logrus.Println("encountered error:" + err.Error())
            }

            consumer.MarkProcessed(msg, string(message.Type))
        }
    }
}()

func consumeMessages(config *rakshak_config.Config) {
    kafkaConfig := kafka.Config{Brokers: strings.Split(config.Kafka.Brokers, ",")}
    logrus.Println("brokers %s", config.Kafka.Brokers)
    hermesConsumer, err := hermes.NewConsumer(hermes.Kafka, []string{config.Kafka.Topic}, kafkaConfig)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Println("could not get consumer through hermes %s", err)
    }
    err = hermesConsumer.Start()
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Println("could not start consumer through hermes %s", err)
    }
    conChan, err := hermesConsumer.Consume()
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Println("not able to start consumer channel %s", err)
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case msg, ok := <-conChan:
                if !ok {
                    logrus.Println("could not consume message")
                }

                logrus.Println("kafka msg string: %s", string(msg.Msg[:]))

                hermesConsumer.MarkProcessed(msg, "")
            }
        }
    }()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could u elaborate on not started gracefully? Any exceptions in logs?

Comment: @IndraneelBende - We got no exceptions but some warnings(correupted file index, trying to rebuild it.). But there is no problem whatsoever when we start the consumer manually. It only happens when we try to consume through the above mentioned code.